# python-measure function time

Tags: python, function, time, measure

I am having a problem with measuring the time of a function.

My function is a "linear search":

```
def linear_search(obj, item,):
    for i in range(0, len(obj)):
        if obj[i] == item:
        return i
    return -1
```

And I made another function that measures the time 100 times and adds all the results to a list:

```
def measureTime(a):
    nl=[]
    import random
    import time
    for x in range(0,100): #calculating time
        start = time.time() 
        a   
        end =time.time()
        times=end-start
        nl.append(times)
    return nl
```

When I'm using `measureTime(linear_search(list,random.choice(range(0,50))))`, the function always returns `[0.0]`.

What can cause this problem? Thanks.

Comment: because your method a isn't called within the loop, but only once before you call the method

Comment: i cant call to a function inside a function? how can i solve that? thanks

Comment: You can pass around a function as argument to another function, but that requires a different syntax. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following example, don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve so I guessed it ;)

```
import random
import time

def measureTime(method, n, *args):
    start = time.time()
    for _ in xrange(n):
        method(*args)
    end = time.time()
    return (end - start) / n

def linear_search(lst, item):
    for i, o in enumerate(lst):
        if o == item:
            return i
    return -1

lst = [random.randint(0, 10**6) for _ in xrange(10**6)]
repetitions = 100
for _ in xrange(10):
    item = random.randint(0, 10**6)
    print 'average runtime =', 
    print measureTime(linear_search, repetitions, lst, item) * 1000, 'ms'
```

Answer (score 1):

you are actually passing the result of `linear_search` into function `measureTime`, you need to pass in the function and arguments instead for them to be execute inside `measureTime` function like @martijnn2008 answer

Or better wise you can consider using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module to to the job for you

```
from functools import partial
import timeit
def measureTime(n, f, *args):
    # return average runtime for n number of times
    # use a for loop with number=1 to get all individual n runtime
    return timeit.timeit(partial(f, *args), number=n)

# running within the module
measureTime(100, linear_search, list, random.choice(range(0,50)))

# if running interactively outside the module, use below, lets say your module name mymodule
mymodule.measureTime(100, mymodule.linear_search, mymodule.list, mymodule.random.choice(range(0,50)))
```